# Java IntelliJ turotorial new project issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am starting to learn the basics of Java using IntelliJ IDEA. I am currently watching Code with Mosh Java turotrial on youtube. I have a problem at the very begining when starting a new project. When naming the project  no base package box is shown. What Am I doing wrong?

[Mosh IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10KE6.png)

[My IntelliJ screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE2wF.png)

Why am not getting the box where to name the base package?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Project wizard was updated in the newest IDE versions. You can create a project as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html and add package by right-clicking on the sources root in the Project tool window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, you can create any package whenever you want on the created project.